# Chrome picture overlays table border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have Html code with lot of tables and an image, which overlays the boder of the table in Google Chrome! It depends on the browser zoom. 
Firefox and Edge are doing well!

As you can see
[how it looks right now (Firefox 57 and Chrome 63).](https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=55581418)

The [img] tag has no css but it is inside of class

```
    .footerContent div {
    color:#707070;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:125%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrufkza4/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set this in the css:

```
.footerContent  div img {
  max-height:100%
}
```